# One liner for iterating through two lists and removing item from one if exists in the other

Tags: python

Have two lists:

```
one = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee']
two = ['aaa', 'qqq', 'rrr', 'bbb', 'zzz']
```

Currently I searched through both and if one exists in the other it is removed like so:

```
for i in one:
    for j in two:
        if j in i:
            one.remove(i)
```

This returns

```
a = ['ccc', 'ddd', 'eee']
```

Just wondering if there's a more pythonic way of doing it than how I currently am?

Comment: how is `a` initialized?

Comment: `j in i` when `i` and `j` are strings checks if `j` is a substring of `i`. I guess you don't actually want that.

Comment: [i for i in one if i not in two]

Comment: `a = [i for i in one if i not in two]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use sets:

```
a = list(set(one) - set(two))
```

gives the expected result.

Comment: This is not guaranteed to keep the order.

Comment: He didn't ask for it to be ordered but just to get that difference in a one-liner.

Comment: OP wants to remove items from a list. To me that implies that the order of the not-removed items is to stay untouched. But OP should clarify.

Comment: `a = list(set(one).difference(set(two)))` also works here.

Answer (score 2):

Use `filter()` built in function:

```
one = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee']
two = ['aaa', 'qqq', 'rrr', 'bbb', 'zzz']

list(filter(lambda a: a not in two, one))
```